# querySelectorAll not recognizing var

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am using casperjs for some webscraping and am having a strange problem.
I want to be able to construct a CSS path from strings and get an array using 'querySelectorAll' like below:

```
var tier = '-ou-';
var index = 'div.list > div > a[href*="' + tier + '"]';
var battles = document.querySelectorAll(index);
```

However, this does not work, and battles returns null.

This version works:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('div.list > div > a[href*="-ou-"]');
```

But none other does.
I also tried:

```
var index = 'div.list > div > a[href*="-ou-"]';
var battles = document.querySelectorAll(String(index));
```

and

```
var index = 'div.list > div > a[href*="-ou-"]';
var battles = document.querySelector(index);
```

and all combinations of the above, just as a sanity check, and none worked. I am relatively new to javascript so I feel I may be missing something obvious, but I have no idea what.

EDIT: 
My entire program is below. As is, it works fine. If the commented line in getBattles is used instead of the one below it, it no longer works (var 'battles' becomes null)

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = 'http://play.pokemonshowdown.com/';
var battles = [];
var tier = '-ou-';
var index = "div.list > div > a[href*=\"" + tier + "\"]";

function getBattles() {
    //var battles = document.querySelectorAll(index);
    var battles = document.querySelectorAll('div.list > div > a[href*="-ou-"]');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(battles, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href');
    });
}

casper
  .start(url)
  .then(function() {
    if(this.exists('div.leftmenu')) {
      this.echo('something works');
    }
    else {
      this.echo('nothing works');
    }
  })
  .thenClick('button[name="roomlist"]')
  .then(function(){
    this.echo("This one is done.");
  })
  .waitForSelector('div.list > div > a', function(){
    battles = this.evaluate(getBattles);
    this.echo(this.getHTML('div.list > div:nth-child(2) > a'));
  })
  .then(function(){
    this.echo("This two is done.");
  });

casper.run(function() {

    this.echo(battles.length + ' battles found:');
    this.echo(' - ' + battles.join('\n - ')).exit();
});
```

Comment: [It works for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/tnf7e7wc/)

Comment: I agree with @Pointy if this your html and code...

`
<div class="list">
    <div>
        <a href="-ou-">item 1</a><br>
        <a href="-ou-">item 2</a><br>
        <a href="-ou1-">item 3 (no match)</a><br>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    var tier = '-ou-';
    var index = 'div.list > div > a[href*="' + tier + '"]';
    var battles = document.querySelectorAll(index);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = battles.length;
</script>
` 
it should work.

Comment: @CoenieRichards The contents of your comment is kinda hard to read, please put it in a jsfiddle or something, and replace it here by a link to the contents

Comment: I don't understand... I tried vinayakj's suggestion and it still didn't work.
I'll post my entire program; it's not long...

Comment: @aduch was about to, but Pointy already did the same kinda thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CasperJS and PhantomJS have two contexts. The inner context which is programmed through [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) is sandboxed. It means that it has no access to variables defined outside. You need to explicitly pass those variables in:

```
var index = 'div.list > div > a[href*="' + tier + '"]';

function getBattles(innerIndex) {
    var battles = document.querySelectorAll(innerIndex);
    return Array.prototype.map.call(battles, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href');
    });
}
...
battles = casper.evaluate(getBattles, index);
```

The PhantomJS documentation of [`evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) has an important note:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

Comment: Thank you! That fixed everything. It was indeed a newbie problem. I'm glad I learned something though.